# Deployng ElasticSearch on Heroku with Tire & Bonsai.io

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, search-engine, elasticsearch

I'm trying to setup the new [Bonsai ElasticSearch](https://addons.heroku.com/bonsai) heroku add-on, but until now I can just run the search on my local developement machine, as soon as deployed on Heroku the same search fails silently, or better, Rails logger doesn't log anything while I get a **500 Internal Server Error**. This are relevant Heroku logs during the failing query (no evident errors found): https://gist.github.com/2867221

I'm looking for some advices on how troubleshoot that. For example, I set `Tire.configure { logger 'elasticsearch.log', :level => 'debug' }` on Bonsai initializer config/initializers/bonsai.rb like the following:

```
Tire.configure { logger 'elasticsearch.log', :level => 'debug' }
if ENV['BONSAI_INDEX_URL']
  Tire.configure do
    url "http://index.bonsai.io"
  end
  BONSAI_INDEX_NAME = ENV['BONSAI_INDEX_URL'][/[^\/]+$/]
else
  app_name = Rails.application.class.parent_name.underscore.dasherize
  app_env = Rails.env
  BONSAI_INDEX_NAME = "#{app_name}-#{app_env}"
end
```

but it logs on a file, which is good for local  but is not accessible after deployed.

Bonsai ElasticSearch is a pritty new on-testing addon, so I wonder if someone of you guys has already had some succesfully experiences deploing that on Heroku and can give me a feedback and some advices.

UPDATE

Setting up logger logger $stdout, :level => 'debug' into Tire.configure finally heroku can log something while it's failing search :

```
2012-06-04T21:36:26+00:00 heroku[router]: GET gitwatcher.com/categories?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=Asynchronous+Web+Frameworks dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=32ms status=500 bytes=728
2012-06-04T21:36:26+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 93.34.212.216 - - [04/Jun/2012:21:36:26 +0000] "GET /categories?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=Asynchronous+Web+Frameworks HTTP/1.1" 500 728 "http://gitwatcher.com/categories" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" gitwatcher.com
2012-06-04T21:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]: # 2012-06-04 21:36:26:387 [_search] (["123456789"])
2012-06-04T21:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]: #
2012-06-04T21:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]: curl -X GET "http://index.bonsai.io/123456789/category/_search?load=true&pretty=true" -d '{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"Asynchronous Web Frameworks"}}}'
2012-06-04T21:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-06-04T21:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]: # 2012-06-04 21:36:26:387 [200] (1 msec)
2012-06-04T21:36:26+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

... please see more on issue opened to https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/365

Comment: Horrible but you should be able to crowbar a logger it with `Tire.configure { @logger = Rails.logger} `

Comment: seems Heroku don't like that way: see the logs https://gist.github.com/2869863

Comment: My mistake - forgot that tire's Logger class isn't the standard ruby Logger class. Heroku should be logging your stdout/stderr for you so I'd try Tire.configure {logger $stdout}

Comment: now is heroku is logging, se UPDATE

Comment: For posterity, the Tire setup with Bonsai is much simpler these days: https://gist.github.com/nz/2041121

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for tracking purposes, 
I'll report here (cat&past) the resolution I post on [GitHub Tire issues](https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/365):

```
DEFINETLY WORKS BY:
  1)  dropping out `to_indexed_json` from Category MongoID model ( at the opposit of README indication )
  2)  removing and re-adding Bonsai.io Heroku add-on
  3)  reindexing ElasticSearch by running `heroku run:detached rake environment tire:import CLASS='Category'`
```

... infact, if you just run rake environment tire:import CLASS='Category' FORCE=true it doesn't work on Heroku/Bonsai.io, becuse of Bonsai authorized operation :

```
  2012-06-11T20:39:30+00:00 app[run.1]: curl -X DELETE http://index.bonsai.io/my-fake-index-11223344
  2012-06-11T20:39:30+00:00 app[run.1]: # 2012-06-11 20:39:30:749 [401]
  2012-06-11T20:39:30+00:00 app[run.1]: #
  2012-06-11T20:39:30+00:00 app[run.1]: # "{\"error\": \"Not authorized: Some endpoints are admin-only, ask support@onemorecloud.com.\"}\n"
```

than if you want to reset/reindex your eventually dirty data, the only way is dropping the Bonsai add-on and recreate:

```
  heroku addons:remove bonsai:test
  heroku addons:add bonsai:test
```

That saied, I really had a dirty data indicated by :

```
  BSON::InvalidObjectId (illegal ObjectId format: LAm-hNglS5mbrMzDlVVHCQ):
  app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:25:in `index'
```

If you'll need the full gem stack to compare with other cases, here it is: https://gist.github.com/2912881